# Search database for rows with two queries mysql /php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with journeys in, I'm trying to find all results in the table that pass both queries (like INTERSECT) but I can only get it to give me two sets of results. The queries search all records within a radius at both ends sql is the start of journey and sql2 is end of journey

```html
<?php

include_once 'dbconnect.php';


     // Get lat and long by address 
     $dlocation = 'SW1A 0AA';        
        $address = $dlocation; // Google HQ
        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
        $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
        $output= json_decode($geocode);
        $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $lng = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
        
        // Get lat and long by address 
     $dlocation = 'bb97bp';        
        $address = $dlocation; // Google HQ
        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
        $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
        $output= json_decode($geocode);
        $lat2 = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $lng2 = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

$sql = "SELECT adpastrip_id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat1 ) ) * cos( radians( long1 ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat1 ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM addgoodstrip HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";
$result = $con->query($sql);                           
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $id = $row['adpastrip_id'];   
    }
}
$sql2 = "SELECT adpastrip_id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat2) ) * cos( radians( lat2 ) ) * cos( radians( long2 ) - radians($lng2) ) + sin( radians($lat2) ) * sin( radians( lat2 ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM addgoodstrip HAVING distance < 10  ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20 ";
$result2 = $con->query($sql2);                           
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
     $id2 = $row2['adpastrip_id'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does result building while loops are actual code? I know it's not directly related to question, but its confusing, because with these loops no answer would be helpful. If you know what you're doing there then it's better to write some general comment than faulty dummy code (you don't build result set there - just store last iterated value, and you don't use distance values coming from query). Beside that - why don't you just use one query? It's simple logic.